# What is the 'n_components' parameter for tweetopic.dmm.DMM class?

Tags: python, topic-modeling, tweets

I am working on a project topic modeling tweets using the tweetopic Python library. I want to understand what the parameter "n_components" for the tweetopic.dmm.DMM class is. I see in the documentation it's described as the "Number of mixture components in the model." I'm new to topic modeling, so am not quite sure what that means.

Thank you!

Here is my code:

tweetopic.dmm.DMM(n_components=10, n_iterations=100, alpha: float = 0.1, beta: float = 0.1)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Tweetopic is like any other sklearn-compatible topic model. In all of sklearn's topic models you specify the number of topics with `n_components`.

I might change the documentation so that this gets clearer. It says mixture components, because DMM is a mixture-model, meaning that it assumes that all texts come from a mixture of distributions, and each distribution (component) can be thought of as a topic.
I hope I could be of help :)